# SPSS Automatic Linear Regression - Run best function

Tags: function, formula, linear-regression, spss

I have a data set with a target and 200+ independent variables and have run a automatic linear regression to determine the predictable factors that explain between 70-80% of the variance.

What I need to do now is run that function through the data and see the predicted value from each row. Since there are forty+ factors I don't want to transform through a formula in the data set.

Is there a way to apply your regression formula to the data set?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the `REGRESSION` command there is an option to save predicted scores. So at the time of running the regression model it shall simultaneously apply the model formula to the cases also.

Answer (score 0):

The question suggests that ALM (Automatic Modeling) was used rather than the standard regression command.  But both standard regression and ALM allow you to save the model (on the Model Options tab for ALM).  Then you can use Utilities > Scoring Wizard to apply the model to the original data or other datasets.